# Share album photo in Page Feed with geotargeting

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, photo, facebook-page

I need to post a photo already present in a page's Photo Album to the same page's Feed, in a way similar to the Share functionality - which means with the bigger display, and allowing me to geotarget the post.

I've tried several approaches (among others, simply specifying `"type": "photo"`), but somehow always end up with a Feed post `"type": "link"` rather than `"type": "photo"` as generated by Facebook when sharing a photo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to do that is to post to '/me/links' (instead of '/me/feed') and set the 'link' to 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=<id_of_the_photo>'. That will effectively share the photo in the user's feed, showing a bigger picture. You can add a personal message (using the 'message' field) but I don't think it's possible to geotag a shared photo.

Posting to '/me/feed' with 'type: photo' only works if the user is the owner of the photo (in that case, set 'object_id' to the photo id).

Comment: It seems as though this type of link to a photo page has now been blocked by Facebook.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case today.  You get this response:
'"error": {
    "message": "(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1500
  }'